# Are there such prime giving functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, big-list

Here let us define a function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ , such that for every $n$ , The sequence $\{f(n) ,f(n)+1 ,f(n)+2 , f(n)+3, \dots , f(n)+n\}$ contains atleast $1$ prime . Let us call it prime giving function

It can be shown that $d(x)$ -number of divisors of $x$ is one such prime giving function by the combination of Bernard's postulate and prime no. theorem 
. The question is  **which are the other such prime giving functions ?** And what are the proofs that they posses such properties?

Comment: There's nothing special about $d(n)$; again by Bertrand's postulate, every function $f()$ satisfying $f(n)\leq n$ for all $n$ works.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki -let us expect functions of a number theoretic twist like partition , prime counting etc

Comment: In that case, what's your expectation for a proof that doesn't just proceed through the known variants of Bertrand's postulate along with some basic counting argument?  (e.g., by Baker-Harman-Pintz, almost any increasing $f()$ that satisfies $f(n)\in o(n^{40/21})$, such as the prime enumeration function; prime counting already falls trivially to the previous version).  By and large the values of these functions don't have many properties that differentiate them from 'random' functions in their general growth class.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry if I am too high in my demands but what I mean is any number theoretic functions

Comment: Shivam, I'm just not sure what you're expecting out of an answer to this question.  What I'm saying is that those functions don't have any 'special' properties; you can more-or-less answer this question just by looking at the growth rate of the function in question, along with possibly some 'local' checking for small $n$.  I'm just trying to figure out if you have any reason to suspect that there might be some other answer or special properties of the particular functions you're interested in.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki just out of curiosity